# Connecting to socket.io 1.x manually using websockets, capacity testing

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku, socket.io

I am working with a nodejs express server which uses socket.io to communicate an iOS client, and am having a little trouble trying to test how many clients can connect and exchange data at any one time.

My goal is to be able to run a script which connects to socket.io with thousands of different sessions, as well as send and receive data to understand our system's scale. Currently we are using a single dyno on Heroku but will likely be considering other options on AWS soon.

I have found code which should do what I am trying to do for earlier versions of socket.io, such as [this](https://github.com/drewww/socket.io-benchmarking), but have had issues since it seems v1.x has a very different handshake protocol. I tried out using the [socket.io-client](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-client) package, but trying to connect multiple times only simulates use of one session, I need to simulate many in independent users.

I have been picking apart the socket.io-client code, but have only gotten so far as creating a connection - I am stuck on the sending data part. If anyone has any knowledge or could point to some written resources on how data is sent between a client and a socket.io server, it would help me out a lot.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var needle = require('needle'),
    WebSocket = require('ws'),
    BASE_URL = 'url-to-socket-host:5002';

var connectionNo = 0;
needle.get('http://' + BASE_URL + '/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1416506501335-0',        function (err, resp) {

    // parse the sid
    var resp = JSON.parse(resp.body.toString().substring(5, resp.body.toString().length));

    // use the sid to connect using websockets
    var url = 'ws://' + BASE_URL + '/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=' + resp.sid;
    console.log(connectionNo + ' with sid: ' + resp.sid);
    var socket = new WebSocket(url, void(0), {
        agent: false
    });

    socket.on('open', function () {
        console.log('Websocket connected: ' + connectionNo);

        // I don't understand how to send data to the server here,
        // from looking at the source code it should use some kind 
        // of binary encoding, any ideas?

        socket.on('message', function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        });
    });
});
```

I will continue deconstructing the socket.io-client code but if anyone has any clues or recourses that may help, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [github.com/Automattic/socket.io-parser](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-parser)

Comment: Great, thanks - I must have missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up setting for using the socket.io-client npm package which has the ability to connect to a new session on every connection. I found an example benchmark in [this issue](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/1718).

There is not so much need for me to manually connect to socket.io using pure websockets and HTTP, but thanks to Yannik for pointing out the [parser](http://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-parser) in use. The spec of the inner workings of v1.x can be found [here](https://github.com/automattic/socket.io-protocol).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem my reside in the fact that you are not using socket.io in your client code.  You have imported ('ws') which is another module whose docs are here: https://www.npmjs.org/package/ws.

You probably want to `ws.send('something');`.  When you receive a message in ws, it also comes with an object with a property indicating whether it is binary data or not.  If it is, you will need to concatenate the chunks incrementally.  There is a canonical way to do this which you can find via google.  But it looks a little like this:

```
var message;
socketConnection.on('data', function(chunk){ message += chunk});
```

Comment: I understand that `ws` is a separate module. I am trying to emulate what the `socket.io` client side code does using the `ws` package since using the `socket.io-client` package only allows me to connect using one session. The question is not about how to use the `ws` module, but trying to understand how `socket.io` transmits data from the client to the server and vice versa.